# Grep - returning both the line number and the name of the file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I have a number of log files in a directory. I am trying to write a script to search all the log files for a string and echo the name of the files and the line number that the string is found.

I figure I will probably have to use 2 grep's - piping the output of one into the other since the -l option only returns the name of the file and nothing about the line numbers. Any insight in how I can successfully achieve this would be much appreciated.

Many thanks,

Alex

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$ grep -Hn root /etc/passwd
/etc/passwd:1:root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash
```

combining `-H` and `-n` does what you expect.

If you want to echo the required informations without the string :

```
$ grep -Hn root /etc/passwd | cut -d: -f1,2
/etc/passwd:1
```

or with [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) :

```
$ awk -F: '/root/{print "file=" ARGV[1] "\nline=" NR}' /etc/passwd
file=/etc/passwd
line=1
```

if you want to create `shell` variables :

```
$ awk -F: '/root/{print "file=" ARGV[1] "\nline=" NR}' /etc/passwd | bash
$ echo $line
1
$ echo $file
/etc/passwd
```

Comment: Interesting: "if you want to create shell variables"

Answer (score 2):

Use `-H`.  If you are using a grep that does not have `-H`, specify two filenames.  For example:

```
grep -n pattern file /dev/null
```

Answer (score 0):

My version of grep kept returning text from the matching line, which I wasn't sure if you were after...  You can also pipe the output to an `awk` command to have it ONLY print the file name and line number

`grep -Hn "text" . | awk -F: '{print $1 ":" $2}'`